# jQuery Ajax call not returning anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest, slim

I have an Asynchronous call in jQuery where a POST request returns an HTTP 200, but there is no response text or anything to work with from the endpoint in question.

I'm confused as to what could be the cause on my Localhost, as when I use the same call to poll a service like JSONTest, I get a valid object back in return.

This is what the result endpoint looks like, written in PHP using Slim

```
$app->post("/search", function() use ($app) {
    try {
        $request = $app->request;
        $body = $request->getBody();
        $input = json_decode($body);

        //Prepare search string
        $query = "%". $input->query . "%";
        $grade = '%grade ' . $input->grade . "%";
        $meta = $input->meta;

        $proc_results = array();

        $item = new stdClass();
        $item->id = 1;
        $item->source = "source";
        $item->type = "lesson_plan";
        $item->description = "Description of the Lesson Plan";
        $item->date_created = 1234567890;

        $proc_results[] = $item;

        $app->response()->header('Content-Type','application/json');
        $app->response()->body(json_encode($proc_results));

        } catch (Exception $e) {

        }
    });
```

This call does return a JSON response when using a utility like POSTMAN, but when I use the following test jQuery code, I get an Object that has no responseText or any sign that my interpreter has the object.

```
$.ajax({
    "type":"POST",
    "url":"http://localhost:9001/search",
    "data":{"query":"math","grade":"4"}
}).done(function(result) { 
    console.debug(result);
});
```

Am I missing a component in my done() call to poll the resources? Is my Slim call sending malformed JSON? If needed I can get a working demo up online.

Comment: Are the server and the client in the same domain/port?

Comment: Yes, both exist on the port of the test PHP Server, 9001.

Answer (score 0):

Type, url, data should not be strings. Try as not string. It should work. Also the keys of data shouldnot be string.

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/search",
    data:{query:"math",grade:"4"}
}).done(function(result) { 
    console.debug(result);
});
```

Comment: It would also be good to specify the content type and the datatype as well. Should still work fine regardless though.

Comment: The response works and returns a 200, but I am not getting the kind of object expected: `Object {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}`. I am expecting something with `[ { "id":1, } ]` and so forth.

Comment: Then, it is serverside issue. Not ajax issue. Make sure you are returning the right object in right form.

Comment: Wether or not the keys are quoted makes no difference, both are equally valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the datatype to be JSON, expanding on @doniyor's answer:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/search",
    datatype:"json",
    data:{query:"math",grade:"4"}
}).done(function(result) { 
    console.debug(result);
})
```

see: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Seems from your comments that you are looking for JSON as a result.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause: I was not sending valid JSON for PHP to parse. By adding JSON.stringify it responds as expected:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"http://localhost:9001/search",
    dataType:"json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({"query": "math", "grade": "4", "meta": "z"}) 
}).done(function(result) { 
    console.debug(result);
});
```

Thanks guys for helping.